# JavaScript замена определённых символов в строке

Tags: javascript

```js
var daylight = '8 h 47 min';
daylight = daylight.replace('h', 'часов');
daylight = daylight.replace('min', 'минут');
console.log(daylight);
```

В переменной ***daylight*** с помощью метода ***replace()*** я заменил символы на необходимые мне. Но есть ли возможность сократить код с двух строк до одной? То есть произвести замену ***h*** и ***min*** в одной строке кода.

Comment: _"1 часов 21 минут"_

Comment: Для вывода длительности светового дня не критично.

Comment: Ну хоть бы сократил до `ч` и `мин`.

Comment: Вывод будет не в консоль, а озвучиваться. При озвучивании окончание не критично, а вот произношение ***ч*** или ***мин*** не очень.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл ещё более лаконичное решение.

```js
var daylight = '8 h 47 min'
daylight = daylight.replace(/(.+)h(.+)min/, "$1часов$2минут");
console.log(daylight)
```

Answer (score 2):

Устроит?

```js
var daylight = '8 h 47 min'
daylight = daylight.replace('h', 'часов').replace('min', 'минут')
console.log(daylight)
```